# Keyup and paste are not working together in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

while performing a client side search when i am using keyup and paste simultaneously then this code is not working.

```
Template.ActiveTemplateDetails.events = {
    'keyup paste .search': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        var $rows = $('.allTemp tr');
        var val = $.trim($(".search").val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        $rows.show().filter(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).hide()
    }
}
```

if i remove anyone either 'keyup' or 'paste' then this is working fine.
Is there anyway to perform it together.

Answer (score 1):

you need to seperate your events with commas, try this

```
Template.ActiveTemplateDetails.events = {
    'keyup .search, paste .search': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        var $rows = $('.allTemp tr');
        var val = $.trim($(".search").val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        $rows.show().filter(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).hide()
   }
}
```